# How to delete every N:th file in Mac terminal?

Tags: terminal

I'm really sorry if this has been answered already - I couldn't find it.

I've got a directory with approx. 35000 files. For every file there are two copies. They're all named in sequence, like so:

0000001, 0000002, etc

In above example the original files would be named 1, 4, 7, 10, etc.

How do I delete all files but the originals?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand Mac terminal use bash as a shell.
The following shell command will removes files that you want (everything except 1,4,7,10,etc):
I assume that the files are numbered 000number.ext

```
shopt -s extglob; for file in [0-9]*; do number=${file%%.ext}; number=${number##+(0)}; if ((number%3 != 1)); then rm $file; fi; done
```

Some comments: `${file%%.ext}` removes extension from file using special bash syntax to remove suffix from string. If your files have no extension you should remove this command.

`${number##+(0)}` removes leading zeros from number (otherwise the number will be treated as octal by shell). This requires extglob option to be set (since `shopt -s extglob` before the main script).

`((number%3 != 1))` is true only for numbers 1,4,7,10, (that gives remainder 1 when divided by 3).

I suggest you to check first using `echo` instead of `rm` before running this with rm to make sure that everything is as expected.